# Should data for SVM be Scaled, normalized, or both

Tags: machine-learning, svm, normalization, scaling

Let me start off with some quick definitions before I ask my question.

Scaling - Change the range of attributes and transform them into a specific scale.

Normalization- Transform attributes so that they have a normal distribution.

Should I scale or normalize my data, or should I scale and normalizing my data when using SVM and similar distance measure learners? I always see people normalizing their data for the SVM, but it seems like scaling would be more important and ideally, maybe you would want to do both? What are your thoughts?